# Depurar RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python-3.x, poo, bucles

Estoy realizando un proyecto el cual necesito que este constantemente censando la entrada por lo cual necesito que se comporte como un loop infinito pero el problema es que después de varias lecturas me da el error de **maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison**, lo que necesito es que mi programa funcione como un loop infinito pero evitando este problema. cualquier tipo de ayuda se agradecerá mucho

```
codigo = input('leyendo codigo')

class LecturaCodigo:

    def __init__(self, codigo):
        self.corte = None
        self.subcadena1 = None
        self.subcadena = None
        self.familia = None
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.memoriacorte = 0

    def separacionCodigoFamilia(self):
        ini = 2  # posición inicial de la subcadena
        fin = 4  # posición final de la subcadena (excluida)
        subcadena = self.codigo[ini:fin]  # Separamos la variable en los valores que nos sirven para saber el tipo de producto
        self.subcadena = subcadena
        self.separacionCodigoCorte()

    def separacionCodigoCorte(self):
        ini1 = 4  # posición inicial de la subcadena
        fin2 = 7  # posición final de la subcadena (excluida)
        subcadena1 = self.codigo[ini1:fin2]  # lo mismo que lo anterior
        self.subcadena1 = subcadena1
        self.distincionCorte()

    def distincionCorte(self):

        if self.subcadena == "01":  # Dividimos la lectura de codigo para saber tipo de familia
            if self.subcadena1 == "001":  # Por codigo de barras EAN 13 sabemos el tipo de corte que es por la disposicion del mismo
                corte = "Aguja"
                self.memoriacorte = 11
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()
            elif self.subcadena1 == "002":
                corte = "Paleta"
                self.memoriacorte = 12
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()
            elif self.subcadena1 == "003":
                corte = "Lomillo"
                self.memoriacorte = 13
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()

        elif self.subcadena == "02":  # Dividimos la lectura del codigo para saber que tipo de familia es
            if self.subcadena1 == "001":
                corte = "Nalga"
                self.memoriacorte = 21
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()
            if self.subcadena1 == "002":
                corte = "Colita"
                self.memoriacorte = 22
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()
            if self.subcadena1 == "003":
                corte = "Bola de lomo"
                self.memoriacorte = 23
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()

        if self.subcadena == "03":
            if self.subcadena1 == "001":
                corte = "Hígado"
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()
            if self.subcadena1 == "002":
                corte = "Lengua"
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()
            if self.subcadena1 == "003":
                corte = "Mondongo"
                self.corte = corte
                self.distincionFamilia()

    def distincionFamilia(self):

        if self.corte == "Aguja":
            familia = 'Frontal'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()
        if self.corte == "Paleta":
            familia = 'Frontal'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()
        if self.corte == "Lomillo":
            familia = 'Frontal'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()

        if self.corte == "Nalga":
            familia = 'Trasero'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()
        if self.corte == "Colita":
            familia = 'Trasero'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()
        if self.corte == "Bola de lomo":
            familia = 'Trasero'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()

        if self.corte == "Hígado":
            familia = 'Menudencia'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()
        if self.corte == "Mondongo":
            familia = 'Menudencia'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()
        if self.corte == "Lengua":
            familia = 'Menudencia'
            self.familia = familia
            self.volver()

    def volver(self):
        codigo = input('codigo: ')
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.separacionCodigoFamilia()
x = LecturaCodigo(codigo)
x.separacionCodigoFamilia()
```

como ven el proyecto lee un codigo de barras (numero de 13 dígitos) y lo separa para obtener la información dentro del codigo. una vez obtenido esta información se vuelve al inicio con el fin de volver a leer otro codigo y obtener sus datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código se puede simplificar aplicando refactoring, que consiste simplemente en reordenar el código sin cambiar su operación.

En este caso, hay mucho código repetido y todas las llamadas a métodos se pueden obviar, incluyendo el código directamente.

Hay errores conceptuales que elimine directamente, como la método `volver()`, que es la causa inmediata de la recursión infinita.

```
class LecturaCodigo:

    def __init__(self, codigo):
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.corte = None
        self.familia = None
        self.memoriacorte = 0

        self.subcadena = self.codigo[2:4]  # Separamos la variable en los valores que nos sirven para saber el tipo de producto
        self.subcadena1 = self.codigo[4:7]  # lo mismo que lo anterior

        if self.subcadena == "01":  # Dividimos la lectura de codigo para saber tipo de familia
            self.familia = 'Frontal'
            if self.subcadena1 == "001":  # Por codigo de barras EAN 13 sabemos el tipo de corte que es por la disposicion del mismo
                self.corte = "Aguja"
                self.memoriacorte = 11
            elif self.subcadena1 == "002":
                self.corte = "Paleta"
                self.memoriacorte = 12
            elif self.subcadena1 == "003":
                self.corte = "Lomillo"
                self.memoriacorte = 13

        elif self.subcadena == "02":  # Dividimos la lectura del codigo para saber que tipo de familia es
            self.familia = 'Trasero'
            if self.subcadena1 == "001":
                self.corte = "Nalga"
                self.memoriacorte = 21
            if self.subcadena1 == "002":
                self.corte = "Colita"
                self.memoriacorte = 22
            if self.subcadena1 == "003":
                self.corte = "Bola de lomo"
                self.memoriacorte = 23

        elif self.subcadena == "03":
            self.familia = 'Menudencia'
            if self.subcadena1 == "001":
                self.corte = "Hígado"
            if self.subcadena1 == "002":
                self.corte = "Lengua"
            if self.subcadena1 == "003":
                self.corte = "Mondongo"
```

En resumen, la clase se limita a tomar un código, parsearlo e inicializar algunos campos. En estricto rigor, no tiene sentido declarar una clase, pues igual te sirve una simple función que te devuelva una tupla de valores.

En lugar de todos esos `if` anidamos sería más conveniente usar diccionarios. Con eso el catálogo de productos puede crecer sin necesidad de alterar el código.

Para pedir códigos en un ciclo infinito, puedes hacerlo así:

```
while True:
    codigo = input('codigo: ')
    x = LecturaCodigo(codigo)
    print(x.codigo)
    print(x.subcadena, x.familia)
    print(x.subcadena1)
    print(x.corte)
```

Nota que el objeto `x` se crea en cada iteración, pasandole el `codigo` ingresado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Candid Moe, tus comentarios también son de mucha ayuda. Apenas estoy aprendiendo todo el tema de programación en python, la idea es ir formándome. Muchas gracias y cualquier libro, curso o tutorial que me recomiendes también seria de mucha ayuda. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Irónico. Un **volver** que en realidad no vuelve.